# How to write a path file in XML?

Tags: xml

How can I write a directory path or file path into a xml file?
For a URL it works so:

```
<New>
  <ID>8b269f29-69a1-4551-8d72-4602df4e2c7e</ID>
  <Title>Industry Rallies Against Ariz. Rental Car Tax</Title>
  <SourceUrl>http://www.autorentalnews.com/t_inside.cfm?action=news_pick&amp storyID=36229</SourceUrl>**
```

But how does it look for a directory (for example: `H: //`)?
Also: `<Source>H:/Test/Testfile.csv</Source>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML itself places no constraints on file paths; it is up to the particular application that uses the XML to specify the format, possibly via an XSD.

Having said that, most applications for an element named `SourceURL` would use a URL format.  For local files such as `H:/Test/Testfile.csv`, the format would likely be:

```
file:///H:/Test/Testfile.csv
```